# Screencapture does not include windows

Tags: big-sur, screen, screen-capture

I'm trying to take a screenshot of my main screen, but `screencapture -x -Jwindow 1.png` does not include windows, so a screenshot contains only my wallpaper.
Basically, I want `screencapture` to work the same way as `command + shift + 3` does.

Edit: I don't want to allow user to select windows manually using `-W`

Edit 2: Big Sur v11.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of searching, I found out that a program, that runs the command, should be allowed in Screen Recording in `System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Screen Recording`

Answer (score 0):

`-J` is an interactive mode control, you don't need that.  From the man page...

> ```
>  -J      <style> Sets the starting style of interfactive capture "selection","window","video".
> ```

`screencapture -x 1.png` is all you need.

Comment: This doesn't work, takes picture of my wallpaper and no windows... How likely this is a bug?

Comment: It's not a bug.  As you determined in your cross-posting on Reddit, your application does not have the Screen Recording permission.